# wordpress images not display

Tags: images

my .htaccess code

## BEGIN WordPress

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

[image]

Comment: We can't tell you anything like this. It most definitely has nothing to do with your .htaccess file. Did you change the URL of website lately?

Comment: I have already change permalinks and permission

Comment: That's not what I asked.

Comment: yes it isnot worked

Comment: Still not what I asked. Did you migrate the website to a new domain or is this maybe a copy from the website on a staging or local environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got problem it is hosting server problem

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have images in your uploads folder
2. Media > Settings set your folder to where the images are, if there is no option chech the url under wp-options in mysql
   3.In your /wp-content folder, you should find your /uploads folder. Check the permissions assigned to this folder. If it’s anything other than 755 (or 777, though this might present a security risk), change the permissions. Go back to your Settings => Media page in your WordPress dashboard, and then uncheck the Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders option. Now check again to see if the thumbnails are loading. If so, great! If not, move on to the next and final solution.
3. change permalinks to other setting, save, check now